# http: From python request to equivalent curl command

Tags: python, http, curl, python-requests

I want to make an upload to Amazon s3 via MS-Flow. The http post via python looks like this

```
    with open('../myfile.txt', 'rb') as f:
        files = {'file': (object_name, f)}
        http_response = requests.post(
            <aws-s3-url>, 
            data={
                'key': 'myfile.txt', 
                'x-amz-algorithm': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256', 
                'x-amz-credential': '<creds>',
                'x-amz-date': '20200529T120357Z', 
                'policy': '<policy>', 
                'x-amz-signature': '<signature>'
            }, 
            files=files
        )
```

The raw request body and headers look as follows

```
--ed1fdd226f0d04d8691a17ceaf914a7e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

myfile.txt
--ed1fdd226f0d04d8691a17ceaf914a7e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-algorithm"

AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
--ed1fdd226f0d04d8691a17ceaf914a7e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-credential"

<creds>
--ed1fdd226f0d04d8691a17ceaf914a7e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-date"

20200529T120357Z
--ed1fdd226f0d04d8691a17ceaf914a7e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="policy"

<policy>
--ed1fdd226f0d04d8691a17ceaf914a7e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-signature"

<signature>
--ed1fdd226f0d04d8691a17ceaf914a7e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="myfile.txt"

test test test
--ed1fdd226f0d04d8691a17ceaf914a7e--
```

and

```
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.23.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '1287', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=ed1fdd226f0d04d8691a17ceaf914a7e'}
```

Sending the request via python works fine.
But when I use the raw http-request-body in MS-Flow or via curl, it fails with

```
The body of your POST request is not well-formed multipart/form-data.
```

The curl command I use is

```
curl \
-d "--ed1fdd226f0d04d8691a17ceaf914a7e\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="key"\r\n\r\nmyfile.txt\r\n--ed1..." \
-X POST \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
-H "boundary: ed1fdd226f0d04d8691a17ceaf914a7e" \
-H "Accept': */*" \
-H "Connection': keep-alive" \
-H "Accept-Encoding': gzip, deflate" \
<aws-s3-url>
```

I also used

```
-d "$(cat body)"
```

instead of the raw string. This changed the line-breaks from "\r\n" to "\n" but did not help.

My question is twofold:

1. How do I correctly derive a working curl command from the above python request? (Possibly even the correct format of the body I would need to enter in MS-Flow)
2. Why does my approach not work?

Would be glad if someone could help. Thanks a lot in advance and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--data` alias `-d` encodes the given string with URL-encoding. Use `--trace -` to see the resulting mess that goes out to the server.

If you have already encoded data like this, you need to use `--data-binary` instead.

You can also use `-F key=value` to specify each field individually and send them as multipart form data, which is less error-prone because you don't have to do the encoding yourself.

Comment: Tanks for your help @Thomas, but it seems to not be the answer. I used --trace in both cases (using --data-binary and --data) and as far as I could tell, there is no difference. Also the result on my local test server is the same in both cases and the body is not parsed successfully.

The main difference I can see between sending the request via python requests.post and using curl (in any case) is that when using python the request.data contains normal single backslashes, while the curl data escapes them with double backslash '\\'. Any idea why?

The approach using -F worked fine btw..

Comment: That's probably because the shell is also mutilating the string, because it's in double quotes. Single quotes might help, but I'd recommend to just use `-F` and let `curl` worry about the escaping.